# Why Mi Mover doesn't move apps but samsung smart switch can?

Tags: device-migration

I move all apps to mi mover.

1. Some apps are moved
2. Another apps have a message "not installed"

This is weird. The whole point of using mi mover is so I don't have to reinstall all those apps one by one.

So I reinstall one by one.

Then I tried to move the apps again.

Now it seems to be working.

However, when I open whatsapp in the new phone I do not see my old whatsapp. I basically have to input my phone number again and uses back up again.

So basically it's useless.

I have to reinstall every app and move them like normal like usual.

So what's the point of using mi mover?

When I use samsung switch I think I got things moving quickly.

Why the differences?

Comment: If the app uses the AndroidKeyStore it can't be migrated because the cryptographic keys can't be extracted from the AndroidKeyStore, they can only be used on that device. If an app uses such a key to encrypt it's user data then migration will always fail.

Comment: I am quite sure I can move using samsung smart switch just fine.